# Expo standalone iOS build crashes on splash screen on Simulator and Testflight

Tags: ios, crash, expo, ios-simulator, testflight

I developed a marketplace app using Expo. It works fine on Expo Go both on Android and iOS, as well as a standalone app for Android. The problem is when I build a .tar for iOS simulator or when I upload to Testflight to test it. Then it crashes right after showing the splash screen. I use a managed workflow, and I think I followed all the instructions.

Here's the crash log:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'ExpoFatalError', reason: 'Expo encountered a fatal error: Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called
CoreSimulator 757.5 - Device: iPhone 12 (0D59D0C0-2D3B-40ED-A8E2-DA0B1417C29C) - Runtime: iOS 14.5 (18E182) - DeviceType: iPhone 12

    Application Specific Backtrace 1:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20422fba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20193ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   ComGrabbiGrabbiapp                  0x000000010b375821 -[EXAppViewController maybeShowError:] + 506
    3   ComGrabbiGrabbiapp                  0x000000010b396dce handleFatalReactError_block_invoke_2 + 574
    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201078df _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201156ca _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 109
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201078df _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20114a27 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1045
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203908f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038b169 __CFRunLoopRun + 2781
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2038a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2b874d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c14df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246c639c UIApplicationMain + 101
    14  ComGrabbiGrabbiapp                  0x000000010b1461d0 main + 80
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff2025abbd start + 1
    
    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff60309946 __pthread_kill + 10
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff60343615 pthread_kill + 263
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff200fbd4f __abort + 139
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff200fbcc4 abort + 135
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff20254692 abort_message + 241
    5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff20245dfd demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
    6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff20179ace _objc_terminate() + 96
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff20253aa7 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff20253a49 std::terminate() + 41
    9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201078f3 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
    10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201156ca _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 109
    11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff201078df _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff20114a27 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1045
    13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff203908f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2038b169 __CFRunLoopRun + 2781
    15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2038a1a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    16  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x00007fff2b874d85 GSEventRunModal + 139
    17  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00007fff246c14df -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    18  com.apple.UIKitCore             0x00007fff246c639c UIApplicationMain + 101
    19  com.grabbi.grabbiapp            0x000000010b1461d0 main + 80
    20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2025abbd start + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a weekend of debugging I fixed it. I had my main app component (in Expo) wrapped in a Stripe Provider component. Since I wasn't using Stripe but Paypal for checkout, I deleted the Stripe wrapper and now it works.

```
  if(fontsLoaded){
return (
    <StripeProvider
        publishableKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        urlScheme="your-url-scheme" // required for 3D Secure and bank redirects
        merchantIdentifier="merchant.com.{{YOUR_APP_NAME}}" // required for Apple Pay
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <RootRouter />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    </StripeProvider>
);
```